# How to push a page than overlaying it

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, user-interface, overlay

I dont know the technical terms for what am trying to achieve here. I would be explaining it in layman terms and hope to learn:

I have created a browser extension which depending on some conditions being met overlays a page on the left side of the browser. Now I want to push the page instead of overlaying such that the existing browser page gets shortened by the size of the pushed page.

(PS: This terminology is completely new to me so feel free to edit the question if you feel so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do it is to inject an iframe on the page and display the overlay page inside this iframe. Make the iframe as absolute. Add the the margin to the body tag which should be equal to the width of the iframe. That'd satisfy your requirements.

HTML:

```
<h1>Sample</h1>
<p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p>
<iframe id="iframex" src="http://vivekgupta.com"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
body{
margin-right:200px;
}
#iframex {
    border:0;
    margin:0
    padding:0;
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YLMWe/

Comment: pardon me for my ignorance on this. Can you share some reference for the same??

Comment: okk @vivek that exactly what we are doing...but its not serving our purpose. It just overlays on the current webpage. What I want to do is to create an extra space displaying the results and shorten the web page by that space.

Comment: @user2129794 I've modified my answer and added a fiddle. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks @Vivek ... I think it should do what am looking for :)